# SQL server -Multiple address joins in from clause

Tags: sql-server

Ok, so I might be trying to do this all wrong, but here it goes.

In my data I have customer seq which is where the order was shipped to.  But, since some orders are dropped shipped they have a different customer number and seq kept in a different table.

So basically, I want to say

```
if custaddr.country <> "" then custaddr.country, else DR.country
```

the from clause I currently have looks like this
CO is order table
Coitem is line of order 
co_ship is shipped line
custaddr is customer address
if the order is drop ship, the customer and seq is pulled from coitem instead of co.

```
from 
    co  inner join coitem on co.co_num = coitem.co_num
        inner join co_ship on (co_ship.co_num = coitem.co_num and co_ship.co_line = coitem.co_line and co_ship.co_release = coitem.co_release)
        inner join custaddr on (co.cust_num = custaddr.cust_num and co.cust_seq = custaddr.cust_seq)
        inner join custaddr DR on (coitem.cust_num = custaddr.cust_num and coitem.cust_seq = custaddr.cust_seq)
```

when I run this, with the last inner join active I get no results.

Comment: you probably want `... = dr.cust_num` in the join clause for the second `custaddr DR` join. You aliased the table, but never USE that alias int he join clause, so you're using values joined in the FIRST usage of `custaddr`.

Comment: What results do you have that you would expect to get?  In addition to what Marc said, if you use INNER joins you will only get rows that satisfy BOTH joins to `custaddr`.   Maybe you really want to use OUTER joins here.

Comment: thank you, Marc was right on the syntax part!! and Tab is right, once I changed to outer joins, I got the results I wanted.